# global ARG variable was changed after FROM in multi stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

Using global ARG variable in instructions like `FROM`, `RUN`

for example i wanna use `${CUDA_VERSION}` ARG variable in `FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA_VERSION}-devel-ubuntu${UBUNTU_VERSION}` and `libcudnn7=${CUDNN_VERSION}-1+cuda${CUDA_VERSION}` in second build stage

but global ARG variable `${CUDA_VERSION}` was changed that after pass `FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA_VERSION}-devel-ubuntu${UBUNTU_VERSION}` 9.0 to 9.0.176

in Ubuntu 18.04, Docker-CE 18.09.04

i was tried many things

1. Change ARG variable line position in build stage
2. Copy other ARG variable from original ${CUDA_VERSION} variable
3. Making .profile for environment variable in first build stage. and in second stage copy `.profile` file from first stage and apply it using `source` command
4. Using ENV variable(but ENV variable disappear when entered other build stage)

example dockerfile and result of build dockerfile as following

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG handler_file=handler.py
ARG handler_name=Handler
ARG HANDLER_DIR=/handler
ARG HANDLER_FILE=${HANDLER_DIR}/${handler_file}
ARG HANDLER_NAME=${handler_name}

# Global arguments for Nvidia-docker
ARG CUDA_VERSION=9.0
ARG CUDNN_VERSION=7.4.1.5
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=16.04

# == MutiStage Build ==
# 1-Stage
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ARG HANDLER_DIR
ARG HANDLER_FILE
ARG HANDLER_NAME
ARG handler_file
ARG handler_name

ARG CUDA_VERSION
RUN echo "${CUDA_VERSION}"

RUN mkdir -p ${HANDLER_DIR}
WORKDIR ${HANDLER_DIR}
COPY . .
RUN touch ${HANDLER_DIR}/__init__.py

# 2-Stage
FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA_VERSION}-devel-ubuntu${UBUNTU_VERSION}

# For Nvidia-Docker
ARG CUDA_VERSION
ARG CUDNN_VERSION

RUN echo "${CUDA_VERSION}"

# Copy directory from 1-stage
ARG HANDLER_DIR
RUN mkdir -p ${HANDLER_DIR}
WORKDIR ${HANDLER_DIR}
COPY --from=0 ${HANDLER_DIR} .

RUN echo "/usr/local/cuda-${CUDA_VERSION}/extras/CUPTI/lib64" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cupti.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    wget \
    tar \
    libgomp1 \
    libcudnn7=${CUDNN_VERSION}-1+cuda${CUDA_VERSION} \
    python \
        python-dev \
        python-numpy \
        python-pip \
        python-setuptools \
        python3 \
        python3-dev \
        python3-numpy \
    python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-tk \
        libgtk2.0-dev \
    ${ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade \
    pip setuptools

RUN pip3 install --upgrdae pip && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

**Build Message**

```
...

Step 9/33 : FROM python:3.7-alpine
 ---> 2caaa0e9feab

...

Step 16/33 : RUN echo "${CUDA_VERSION}"
 ---> Running in d057b0fd57a7
9.0

...

Step 21/33 : FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA_VERSION}-devel-ubuntu${UBUNTU_VERSION}
 ---> 2f9810b1b916

...

Step 24/33 : RUN echo "${CUDA_VERSION}"
 ---> Running in dc676c2a2992
9.0.176

...

Step 30/33 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   build-essential     wget    tar     libgomp1    libcudnn7=${CUDNN_VERSION}-1+cuda${CUDA_VERSION}    python         python-dev         python-numpy         python-pip         python-setuptools         python3         python3-dev         python3-numpy   python3-pip         python3-setuptools         python3-tk         libgtk2.0-dev     ${ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE}     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 8518fb8d755c

...

E: Version '7.4.1.5-1+cuda9.0.176' for 'libcudnn7' was not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends    build-essential     wget    tar     libgomp1    libcudnn7=${CUDNN_VERSION}-1+cuda${CUDA_VERSION}    python         python-dev         python-numpy         python-pip         python-setuptools         python3         python3-dev         python3-numpy   python3-pip         python3-setuptools         python3-tk         libgtk2.0-dev     ${ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE}     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

The expected result is docker file build successfully

but ARG variable changed causes the following error
`E: Version '7.4.1.5-1+cuda9.0.176' for 'libcudnn7' was not found`

Answer (score 0):

i was resolve my problem as following

and i posted in issue
https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/713

```
# Global arguments for Nvidia-docker
ARG CUDA_VERSION=9.0
ARG CUDNN_VERSION=7.4.1.5
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=16.04
ARG BACKUP=${CUDA_VERSION}

...

RUN echo "/usr/local/cuda-${BACKUP}/extras/CUPTI/lib64" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cupti.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    wget \
    tar \
    libgomp1 \
    libcudnn7=${CUDNN_VERSION}-1+cuda${BACKUP} \
    python \
        python-dev \
        python-numpy \
        python-pip \
        python-setuptools \
        python3 \
        python3-dev \
        python3-numpy \
    python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-tk \
        libgtk2.0-dev \
    ${ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Arguments for Nvidia-Docker
# all combination set in CUDA, cuDNN, Ubuntu is not Incompatible please check REFERENCE OF NVIDIA-DOCKER
# REFERENCE OF NVIDIA-DOCKER 
# https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/

ARG handler_file=handler.py
ARG handler_name=Handler
ARG HANDLER_DIR=/handler
ARG HANDLER_FILE=${HANDLER_DIR}/${handler_file}
ARG HANDLER_NAME=${handler_name}

# Global arguments for Nvidia-docker
ARG CUDA_VERSION=9.0
ARG CUDNN_VERSION=7.4.1.5
ARG UBUNTU_VERSION=16.04
ARG BACKUP=${CUDA_VERSION}

# == MutiStage Build ==
# 1-Stage
# Get watcher - if watcher is uploaded on github, remove this line.
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ARG HANDLER_DIR
ARG HANDLER_FILE
ARG HANDLER_NAME
ARG handler_file
ARG handler_name

ARG BACKUP
ARG CUDA_VERSION
RUN echo "${CUDA_VERSION}"
RUN echo "${BACKUP}"

RUN mkdir -p ${HANDLER_DIR}
WORKDIR ${HANDLER_DIR}
COPY . .
RUN touch ${HANDLER_DIR}/__init__.py

# 2-Stage
FROM nvidia/cuda:${CUDA_VERSION}-devel-ubuntu${UBUNTU_VERSION}

ARG BACKUP
# For Nvidia-Docker
ARG CUDA_VERSION
ARG CUDNN_VERSION

RUN echo "${CUDA_VERSION}"
RUN echo "${BACKUP}"

# Copy directory from 0-stage
ARG HANDLER_DIR
RUN mkdir -p ${HANDLER_DIR}
WORKDIR ${HANDLER_DIR}
COPY --from=0 ${HANDLER_DIR} .

RUN echo "/usr/local/cuda-${BACKUP}/extras/CUPTI/lib64" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cupti.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    wget \
    tar \
    libgomp1 \
    libcudnn7=${CUDNN_VERSION}-1+cuda${BACKUP} \
    python \
        python-dev \
        python-numpy \
        python-pip \
        python-setuptools \
        python3 \
        python3-dev \
        python3-numpy \
    python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-tk \
        libgtk2.0-dev \
    ${ADDITIONAL_PACKAGE} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade \
    pip setuptools

RUN pip3 install --upgrdae pip && \
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```